# Html 5 file upload and how to send a file from a browser to backend

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I've seen a few tutorials of how to use Html5 File API such as this https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ for file uploading. **What I want is a few pointers of how to send all that from a browser to backend and process it there to actually upload files.** In those tutorials it's not shown.

The backend language doesn't matter.

And I don't want to use an external js library, only pure javascript.

Comment: Not certain what Question is?

Comment: See [How can I upload files asynchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Comment: @guest271314, that's not related to my question.

Comment: _"that's not related to my question."_ ? What is Question? Can you include the `html` and `javascript` that you tried at Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @guest271314, are you stupid idiot? re-read it one more time.

Comment: @guest271314, see http://www.wikihow.com/Read-a-Book

Comment: _"@guest271314, are you stupid idiot? re-read it one more time."_ No. Your Question is not clear. In fact, you do not pose a question at all at OP.